# "No space left on device" error and SIGTERM signal when using Spark LSH in EMR

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, lsh

Spark version-2.3.2
EMR - 5.19.0
8 Executors
Each executor - 5 core

What I am trying to do :-
1. millions of numpy features (.npy files) are there in s3.
2. Using spark download all the numpy feature vectors.
3. convert them to Spark Dataframes where the Dataframe schema is feature-name (string) and feature-vector (VectorUDT).
4. Then find the LSH using spark between the data frames.

code:-

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import BucketedRandomProjectionLSH
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('test-app') \
        .getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    features_rdd = sc. \
        binaryFiles("s3://input_path/"). \
        map(
        lambda x: (
            x[0].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0],
            Vectors.dense(np.fromstring(x[1], dtype='<f4'))
        )
    )

    FEATURES_RAW_SCHEMA = StructType([StructField("image_id", StringType(), True),
                                      StructField("feature", VectorUDT(), True)
                                      ])

    features_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(features_rdd, FEATURES_RAW_SCHEMA)
    brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(inputCol="feature", outputCol="hashes", seed=12345, numHashTables=30,
                                      bucketLength=1000)




    model = brp.fit(features_df)

    all_pairs_df = model.approxSimilarityJoin(features_df, features_df, 50.0, distCol="similarity_score").select(
        F.col("datasetA.image_id").alias("image_id1"), F.col("datasetB.image_id").alias("image_id2"),
        F.col("similarity_score"))



    all_pairs_df.write.mode("overwrite").json(
        "s3a://output")
```

Error:-

```
19/01/10 11:20:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 120.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 11, ip-ip1.ec2.internal, executor 5): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:58)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:220)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:173)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillWriter.write(UnsafeSorterSpillWriter.java:133)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.spillIterator(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.spill(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:222)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.createWithExistingInMemorySorter(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeKVExternalSorter.java:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.destructAndCreateExternalSorter(UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.java:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage7.agg_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage7.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage7.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$12$$anon$2.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:633)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

submit script:-

```
sudo -i spark-submit --verbose --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 11 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 8G --driver-cores 5 --driver-memory 8G --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 /home/hadoop/filename.py
```

In some cases the the executors dying with SIGTERM signal I can see in log files. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Buy a larger disk?

Comment: the cluster has good amount of size. the same issue happens even with 1k numpy features. each feature size is ~16KB. so, I am pretty sure its not the disk issue. something else is wrong here.

Comment: Use the Environment tab in web UI to see the mounts in use (e.g. `java.io.tmpdir`). It's possible that the temp directory got filled out.